# Elegant coding for optional arguments and outputs in Python

Tags: python, function

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to write following function without using if statements or less if statements. Depending on the argument I choose I want the function to return different variables.

```
X = np.ones((3,3))
def calculate(X, output2=False, output3=False):
    y1=X*2
    y2=X*3
    y3=X*4

    if (output2==False and output3==False):
        return y1
    if (output2==True and output3==False):
        return y1,y2
    if (output2==False and output3==True):
        return y1,y3
    if (output2==True and output3==True):
        return y1,y2,y3


out1, out3=calculate(X, output3=True)
```

Comment: You could use a tuple and add onto it. With a half dozen optional returns this would make a huge improvement over explicitly listing all the combinations. But with only 2 outputs and 4 combinations I’m not sure it’s any simpler.

Comment: Depending on your needs you can make X itself the condition, removing the need for other params. Or if the condition isn't dependent on X you can have 1 extra param that is an int, and build the if,elif clauses dependent on that.

Comment: `out1, out3=calculate(X, output3=True)` fails if you only return 1 value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return values based on a mask. You can figure out what to return by iterating over the y-vals and the `mask` with `zip`.

```
def calculate(X, output2=False, output3=False):   
    ...
    mask = [True, output2, output3]
    y = [y1, y2, y3]
    return [i for i, j in zip(y, mask) if j]
```

```
out1, out3 = calculate(X, output3=True)

out1
array([[2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2.]])

out3
array([[4., 4., 4.],
       [4., 4., 4.],
       [4., 4., 4.]])
```

If you are returning a single element only, you'd need a slight change. Here's an example:

```
out1, *_ = calculate(X, output3=False)
```

Comment: That depends on the return values all having the same shape and dtype, and it doesn't quite do the right thing when only returning one value. Also, it can result in one array keeping another alive longer than expected.

Comment: @user2357112 I've addressed both your comments.

Comment: Almost. You still return a list in the only-one-output case.

Answer (score 4):

Build the return tuple element by element, then eliminate the tuple if there's only one element:

```
retval = (stuff_always_returned,)
if output2:
    retval += (more_stuff,)
if output3:
    retval += (even_more_stuff,)

if len(retval) == 1:
    return retval[0]
return retval
```

You may also be able to avoid computing the parts of the output you don't need, by moving those computations into the corresponding `if` branches.

```
retval = (stuff_always_returned,)
if output2:
    more_stuff = compute_more_stuff()
    retval += (more_stuff,)
...
```

Comment: `+= (more_stuff,)` doesn't matter much for one or two tuples, but for a lot of them, you'd keep re-creating them, right?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: For a lot of them, yes. It'd be quite unlikely for that to matter unless you start extending the tuple inside a loop; in that case, working with a list until the end would be better. For most reasonable multiple-return-values situations, it's not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
X = np.ones((3,3))
def calculate(X, output2=False, output3=False):
    y1=X*2
    y2=X*3
    y3=X*4

    options = {(0,0):y1,
            (1,0):(y1,y2),
            (0,1):(y1,y3),
            (1,1):(y1,y2,y3)}

    return options.get((output2,output3),(None,None))

out1, out3=calculate(X, output3=True) 


[[ 2.  2.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.]]
[[ 4.  4.  4.]
 [ 4.  4.  4.]
 [ 4.  4.  4.]]
```